# Change array or request data back to query string format

Tags: arrays, laravel, parameters, get, request

```
public function try2(Request $request)
 {
  $search_cons = $request->all();
  //dd($search_cons);
 }
```

the $search_cons is an array from a form submit

Can I change it back to

```
$parameter = ?id=5&name=john&News=new&class=0
```

just like the form submit

```
http:://xxxx/xxx?id=5&name=john&News=new&class=0
```

I know I can do it step by step like

```
$pid=$search_cons['id'];
$pname=$search_cons['name'];
$pnews=$search_cons['News'];
$pclass=$search_cons['class'];

$parameter = ?id=.'$pid'.&name=.'$pname'.&News=.'$pnews.'&class=.'$pclass
```

But it is some slow and cannot suit for any form change.

Can any smart idea to change it from the array?

---

I want got the parameter just like

```
'comefo_findlists?findtable_name=台北市北投區&findtable=a16s&findNews_geography=&wantclass=0&wanttime=1&fl_main_name=&fl_brand_name=&fl_model_name=&fl_location_name=&fl_geography_name=&find02=&pl_main_name=&pl_brand_name=&pl_model_name=&pl_price_name=&pl_count_name=&pl_unit_name=0&pl_location_name=&pl_geography_name='
```

But when I try http_build_query(($request->all())
I got

```
'comefo_findlists?findtable_name=%E5%8F%B0%E5%8C%97%E5%B8%82%E5%8C%97%E6%8A%95%E5%8D%80&amp;findtable=a16s&amp;wantclass=0&amp;wanttime=1&amp;pl_unit_name=0'
```

it miss the key of value=empty? Can show it all and not to miss them as I need the key?

the dd($search_cons); is

[image]

I got this using the http_build_query
[image]
I hope this 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a native function for this, [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), which takes an array and returns a query string (key=value with the appropriate encoding). e.g:

```
http_build_query($request->all());
```

Comment: Wow! It's marvelous! But I find the $parameter is cut half and (1) when I user dd($parameter)have a unicode error (laguage garbled)  (2).when I use ->with('parameter',$parameter) send to the blade I got many =&pl ? make the result cannot be used by the get

Comment: Please update your question to include an example of your input and the error you're receiving.

Comment: I update the my need and http_build_query result above my question~